# Use single quote or double quote for strings in EL

Tags: string, jsf, jsf-2, el, quotes

```
<ui:repeat value="#{coreGridBean.heroBeanList}" var="hero"
    offset="0" step="1" size="#{hero.size}" varStatus="status">
    <tr class="#{status.even ? 'evenColumn' : 'oddColumn'}">
        <td>#{status.index}</td>
        <td>#{hero.id}</td>
        <td>#{hero.race}</td>
        <td>#{hero.name}</td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

I wonder whether the usage of `class="#{status.even ? 'evenColumn' : 'oddColumn'}"` is correct.

I feel a bit guilty of using single quotes instead of double quotes. But in this case, double quote fails, single quote wins.

Comment: You could also use outer single quotes and then use double quotes for the Strings. `class='#{status.even ? "evenColumn" : "oddColumn"}'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. It's also the convention I use: single quotes for strings in EL. It's not only better readable, but it's also friendly for syntax highlighting.

Using double quotes is valid, but harder to interpret when nested in a HTML attribute which is by itself also double quoted.