# JSF outputtext conditional display/styling. Differently depending on condition

Tags: jsf, rendering, conditional-statements

I`m using JSF and I have an output text per example "qwerty" that I want to display / format differently if some conditions will be met.
So per example if:

- cond1 is true then I want to display <del>qwerty</del>
- cond1 is false then I want to display *qwerty*

and so on.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628145/1199132) in order to choose the style you want to apply depending on the condition:

```
<h:outputText value="qwerty" 
    style="#{backingBean.cond1 ? 'text-decoration:line-through;':'fontstyle:italic;'}">
```

And it would be even better if you use css classes in order of inline styles. Good luck!

Using the 'condition' inline in the EL is also possible, see [using greater than logical expression in rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145574/using-greater-than-logical-expression-in-rendered-attribute). Read also the [discussion about using inline in the xhtml or in the javabean](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181691/should-a-complex-el-expression-be-replaced-by-a-single-javabean-getter)

Comment: I thought of that but I thought it is a better more elegant way. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: That is not the most elegant way. You actually create two components in component tree. Also keep [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Comment: It's just a way to give a basic explanation about how conditional rendering-evaluation works in JSF. My second approach is better ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Neat way is to create CSS classes

```
<h:outputText value="qwerty" 
     styleClass="#{backingBean.cond1 ? 'classA' : 'classB'}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

In similar situations, I use following

```
<h:outputText value="yourValueFromYourBeanOrWhatever" styleClass="anArbitraryName#{managedBean.condition}"/>
```

And in my CSS file I define the classes:

```
.anArbitraryNametrue{}
```

and

```
.anArbitraryNamefalse{}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the conditional. Before the interrogation you put the condition. If true, it returns what is before t ":". If it is false, it returns what is behind ":".

```
<h:outputText value="#{condition ? 'true' : 'false'}" />
```