# How to concatenate strings in conditional operator of an EL expression

Tags: jsf, el, string-concatenation, conditional-operator

I want to concatenate `bean.receiver.surname` and `bean.receiver.name` as one string in the following expression. How can I do this?

```
itemLabel="#{bean.receiver == login.current ? bean.sender.surname : bean.receiver.surname bean.receiver.name}"
```

Comment: your question is not clear, to show a value of a entity only use `#{entity.property}` , supposing htat your `entity` is in the scope of JSF beans

Comment: EL ternary operator works fine. Try expression without string concatenation in else part. See [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628145/jsf-2-el-ternary-operator-question)

Comment: No, i want not to display a string, I want to display the property of a bean. Something like this `code`itemLabel="#{mandatoryFriendship.receiver == loginBean.currentMandatory} ? #{mandatoryFriendship.sender.surname}  : #{mandatoryFriendship.receiver.surname} #{mandatoryFriendship.receiver.name}"`code`

Comment: the problem isnt the #{entity.property} ! The problem is TWO #{entity.property} in one condition

Answer (score 3):

Assuming at least EL 2.2 and that the names are non-null Strings you could have an expression of the form:

```
#{condition ? str0 : str1.concat(str2)}
```

For an older version (or null Strings) you could use:

```
#{condition ? str0 : str1}#{condition ? str0 : str2}
```